# HTML input for number and special text - user friendly

Tags: javascript, html

In my html form the inputtag is supposed to be a number (so I specify number type), but some numbers have special meanings. Like the expiry in days input tag can have any number of days but if user wants to specify `No Expiry` I expect `0` as input so to convey that I show placeholder text

```
1, 2, 30, 0 (No Expiry) etc.
```

It doesn't seem user friendly as input can have some number initially, which hides the message and can confuse the user.

Also, I need to take input a number but also allow the user following value:

`Unlimited`

I don't want user to type this. What is best way to handle this?

Comment: This is not really a programming question but more of a UX problem.

Comment: @thatidiotguy i think programmers might have faced this problem often.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on the user experience stack exchange and should be migrated to that exchange

Comment: You've used positives, you've used zero, only you've left is negatives ...

Comment: @Teemu thats why I posted this question. Is there any js library for this.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like a dropdown would work if you don't have to use input tag. As you mentioned that you don't want user to type. So a simple dropdown would be like this:

```
<select>
  <option value="0">No Expiry</option>
  <option value="Unlimited">Unlimited</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <!-- more option -->
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

You can see the effect here: https://jsfiddle.net/nx1Lt86g/

Comment: I can have any number.

Comment: Ok, then it sounds like autocomplete might help, here is an example from jquery ui: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Comment: And also with some help from placeholder.